Windows Service Execution on user level?
I'm writing some window manipulation code and wanna schedule it over a service, which I can activate/deactivate. However, when I set the code to run over the Service and not the user executes the code himself the window manipulation code doesn't work.
std::string cmd1("C:\\Windows\\System32\\" + r + "\\app.exe");
std::system(cmd1.c_str());

this is the code in the service that executes it, and in main.cpp of the app there are functions like:

GetForegroundWindow()
SetWindowPos()
GetWindowRect()

and since the service executes the app.exe the window manipulation doesn't work.
Any fixes?
Thanks!

AFAIK Windows service cannot use or have a UI.

NT Services execute in Session 0. That's a non-interactive session. It doesn't know windows nor input processing. You'll have to launch a process into a user's interactive session to gain access to windowing functionality.

And there are plenty of questions on StackOverflow related to running processes in user  sessions from a service

Instead of running it as a service, run it as a Scheduled Task. Or just some systray app.  All kinds of ways to have code running in the background in the same session as the user.  But let me ask.... what are you really trying to do?  I ask because Windows manipulation code is sort of a weird thing to do.... are you trying to force an app into the foreground?
